# I am making an event listener where I need to put a function but I am having problems in doing so

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, event-handling

I have made a function outside the event listener:

```
function nextSequence(){
  Some something here
}
```

Then I had an event listener:

```
$(document).keydown(
```

after this I used to make a nameless function earlier but now I want to input a function that has been earlier made. So how do I do it

I tried

```
$(document).keydown(nextSequence ())
```

But nothing happened

Comment: `$(document).keydown(nextSequence)` or `$(document).on("keydown",nextSequence)` without the trailing (). If nextSequence returned a function you need to add the () to it in the assignment